# /bin/sh: =: not found when running docker container from custom image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, containers

I try to run a container from a built image and get an error /bin/sh: =:. Is there anyone know how to fix it. Below is my Dockerfile. Both the index.js and package.json are in the same folder with the Dockerfile.

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies":{
    "express":"*"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "start":"node index.js"
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine3.10
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD = ['npm', 'start']
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message? Also post your package.json and index.js

Comment: I have updated my package.json file. The error message only has one line: /bin/sh: =: not found

Comment: It's `CMD ['npm', 'start']` without `=`

Comment: @ThomasSablik ...and either double quotes `CMD ["npm", "start"]` or no punctuation at all `CMD npm start`.

Comment: @MinhDang You seem to have posted a (large, on my screen) screen shot of your `Dockerfile` and not the actual file.  Can you replace the image with the actual text of the file?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated the Dockerfile's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to `CMD` is parsed as a JSON array, which means you have to use double quotes and not single quotes. Additionally, get rid of the `=`

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```